# How to run MULE on local IP?

Tags: web-services, mule, mule-flow

I have a MULE application. It consist of a Flow like below:

```xml
<flow name="article_list">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/jcore/article/list" />
    <component class="com.joshlabs.jcore.article.ArticleList" />
</flow>
```

Now as it can be seen it runs on "localhost".

But everybody is able to access it through my local IP (only if we are on same network). But I don't want that anybody to use these services. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different options:

- Use a firewall (the easiest),
- Protect the HTTP endpoint with Mule/Spring security,
- If your machine has several IPs, bind the endpoint to an IP that isn't reachable from other machines.

Comment: What i find the easiest is blocking the port on which MULE instance is running..!!..n i am looking forward to using Spring security if any need arises..!!